# Apache - protect a subdirectory but not the root

Tags: configuration, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I have a website, it should be accessible by anyone, but one directory should request http authorization.

I have added following lines to website.conf:

```
 <Directory /var/www/website/serverside>
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "Login please"
         AuthUserFile /var/www/website/serverside/.htpasswd
         Require valid-user
 </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/website >
         Allow From All
         Satisfy All
         AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
```

But it requests a password even if I visit the root page! How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're mixing up `Satisfy Any` and `Satisfy All`.

Comment: Also... you should not put your .htpassword file under the documentroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Satisfy All` directive or change it to `Satisfy Any`, as is not needed because you're not using authentication directives for the directory .